# Criar uma div com aparência de balão de quadrinhos

Tags: html, css, css3

Como posso criar uma `div` com aparência de balão de quadrinhos (não sei se essa é a melhor expressão).

Objetivo:

[image: objetivo]

Realidade:

[image: como está ficando]

*Favor ignorar fontes e cores em questão, o foco é ponta da `div`.

Segue o [código no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61jx0dk5/):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outro exemplo aqui:

```
.content_ballon{
    background: #37688D;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 9px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 3px 5px;
}

.ballon img{
    position: absolute;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61jx0dk5/1/)

Ai você movimenta a classe "ballon" para onde quer.

Comment: Valeu cara! Era exatamente isso que procurava obrigado XD

Comment: Por nada, estamos ai pra ajudar.

Comment: Dica de ferramenta para gerar speech bubbles em CSS: http://www.ilikepixels.co.uk/drop/bubbler/

Comment: Bacana esse heim @OnoSendai, não conhecia ainda. Valeu!

Answer (score 8):

### Versão CSS3

HTML

```
<div class="balao">Oi!</div>
```

CSS

```
.balao {
    float:left;
    background-color:#39c;
    border-top:10px solid #39c;
    border-left:10px solid transparent;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bacco/7egdpw0g/)**

### Versão CSS2

HTML

```
<div class="balao">Oi!</div>
```

CSS

```
.balao {
    float:left;
    background-color:#39c;
    border-top:10px solid #39c;
    border-left:10px solid #eee; /* Usar mesma cor do fundo*/
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bacco/cfg7kpq2/)**

Comment: ou `transparent` ;)

Comment: IE7+ eu sei que funciona. Sabe algum outro que dê problema?

Comment: Muito obrigado! diante do projeto a solução funcionaria, valeu

Comment: @beterraba com CSS3 dá pra usar `transparent`, mas precisa de `background-clip: padding-box;`. Pus uma versão CSS3 pra usar sua sugestão.

Comment: Realmente excelente @Bacco ! Só ainda estou tentando entender em como o border-left criou só aquela tirinha, e não colocou a borda inteira verticalmente.

Comment: @AllanRamos espie essa versão para facilitar a visualização: http://jsfiddle.net/Bacco/7egdpw0g/5/ - só tem borda em cima e à esquerda, esse foi o "truque".

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra forma de fazer:

```
.balao {
    background:blue;
    position:relative;
}
.balao:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:-10px;
    top:0;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right:10px solid blue;
}
```

Exemplo completo: **[`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/ogom8ym5/)**

Comment: Muito obrigado extremamente util e sem a necessidade de utilizar imagem ou criar outro elemento, valeu XD